# Recv() returning SOCKET_ERROR when I connect a client to the server instead of blocking and waiting for message

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcp, network-programming

I am relatively new to network programming and multithreading in C++. Currently my recv() call returns an unknown error. I'm not quite sure where the error coming from at the moment and would appreciate some help.

I used putty to connect to the server locally

```
class Threaded_TCPListener{

    int Threaded_TCPListener::Init()
    {
        // Initializing WinSock
        WSADATA wsData;
        WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2,2);

        int winSock = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
        if(winSock != 0)
            return winSock;

        // Creating listening socket
        this->socket = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

        if(this->socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
            return WSAGetLastError();

        // Fill sockaddr with ip addr and port
        sockaddr_in hint;
        hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
        hint.sin_port = htons(this->port);
        inet_pton(AF_INET, this->ipAddress, &hint.sin_addr);

        // Bind hint to socket
        if(bind(this->socket, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            return WSAGetLastError();

        // Start listening on socket
        if(listen(this->socket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            return WSAGetLastError();

        // Accept first client
        this->createAcceptThread();

        return 0;
    }

    int Threaded_TCPListener::Run()
    {
        bool isRunning = true;

        // Read from all clients
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        threads.reserve(this->clients.size());

        // Recv from client sockets
        for (int i=0; i < this->clients.size(); ++i)
        {
            threads.emplace_back(std::thread(&Threaded_TCPListener::receiveFromSocket, this, socket));
        }

        // Wait for all threads to finish
        for(std::thread& t : threads)
        {
            t.detach();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void Threaded_TCPListener::onMessageReceived(int clientSocket, const char* msg, int length)
    {
        Threaded_TCPListener::broadcastToClients(clientSocket, msg, length);

        std::thread t(&Threaded_TCPListener::receiveFromSocket, this, clientSocket);

        t.detach();

        return;
    }

    void Threaded_TCPListener::sendMessageToClient(int clientSocket, const char * msg, int length)
    {
        send(clientSocket, msg, length, 0);

        return;
    }

    void Threaded_TCPListener::broadcastToClients(int senderSocket, const char * msg, int length)
    {
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        threads.reserve(clients.size());

        // Iterate over all clients
        for (int sendSock : this->clients)
        {
            if(sendSock != senderSocket)
                threads.emplace_back(std::thread(&Threaded_TCPListener::sendMessageToClient, this,sendSock, msg, length));
        }

        // Wait for all threads to finish
        for(std::thread& t : threads)
            t.join();

        return;
    }

    void Threaded_TCPListener::createAcceptThread()
    {
        // Start accepting clients on a new thread
        this->listeningThread = std::thread(&Threaded_TCPListener::acceptClient, this);

        this->listeningThread.detach();

        return;
    }

    void Threaded_TCPListener::acceptClient()
    {
        int client = accept(this->socket, nullptr, nullptr);

        // Error
        if(client == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            std::printf("Accept Err: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }
        // Add client to clients queue
        else
        {
            // Add client to queue
            this->clients.emplace(client);

            // Client Connect Confirmation
            onClientConnected(client); // Prints msg on server

            // Create another thread to accept more clients
            this->createAcceptThread();
        }

        return;
    }

    void Threaded_TCPListener::receiveFromSocket(int receivingSocket)
    {
        // Byte storage
        char buff[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];

        // Clear buff
        memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));

        // Receive msg
        int bytesRecvd = recv(receivingSocket, buff, MAX_BUFF_SIZE, 0);
        if(bytesRecvd <= 0)
        {
            char err_buff[1024];
            strerror_s(err_buff, bytesRecvd);

            std::cerr << err_buff;
            // Close client
            this->clients.erase(receivingSocket);
            closesocket(receivingSocket);

            onClientDisconnected(receivingSocket); // Prints msg on server
        }
        else
        {
            onMessageReceived(receivingSocket, buff, bytesRecvd);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a multithreaded TCP 'server' that will handle incoming clients by having an accept thread continuously running (listening for new connections), and a thread waiting with a recv block for each client connected to the server.

Comment: The shown code is incomplete. The definitions of `socket` and `clients` are not provided, but it's extremely unlikely that they are thread safe objects -- they appear to be a plain `int` and a `std::vector` of some sort, as such since they're being accessed by multiple threads this is undefined behavior, and random crashes are fairly likely. This is already a failure. Furthermore, it's unclear how execution reaches `receiveFromSocket()` from the original thread. Key pieces of the code are missing. Please read stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mcve], and [edit] this question accordingly.

Comment: When a Winsock function fails use `WSAGetLastError()` to find out why. There are no "unknown" errors. Your `Run()` is passing the listening `socket` to `receiveFromSocket()` when it should be passing `clients[i]` instead. Also, you should not be creating a new thread for each call to `accept()`. Create one thread that calls `accept()` in a loop for the lifetime of the server.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to include a little as possible but I cut out too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `Init` looks fine:

   - create socket, bind it, listen on it, start accept thread
2. In your accept thread's `acceptClient` looks sort of OK:

   - print some message
   - add the client socket to `clients` queue
   - create a new accept thread
3. Your `Run` makes no sense:

   - create one thread per element in `clients` to receive from the listening `socket`

---

It looks like you are spawning a new thread for every single socket action. That is a pretty wasteful design. As soon as the thread is done it can go back to doing something else.

So creating a new accept thread in `acceptClient` is a waste, you could just loop back to the beginning to `::accept` the next client. Like so:

```
acceptClient() {
  while (alive) {
    int client = accept(socket, ...);
    createClientHandler(client);
  }
}
```

What seems to be missing is spawning a new client thread to service the client socket. You currently do this in `Run`, but that's before any of the clients are actually accepted. And you do it for the *wrong* socket! Instead, you should be spawning the `receiveFromSocket` threads in `acceptClient`, *and* passing it the **client** socket. So that's a bug.

In your `receiveFromSocket` you also need not create another thread to `receiveFromSocket` again -- just loop back to the beginning.

The biggest concern with this thread-per-action design is that you are spawning sender threads on every incoming message. This means you could actually have several sender threads attempting to `::send` on the same TCP socket. That's not very safe.

> The order of calls made to WSASend is also the order in which the buffers are transmitted to the transport layer. WSASend should not be called on the same stream-oriented socket concurrently from different threads, because some Winsock providers may split a large send request into multiple transmissions, and this may lead to unintended data interleaving from multiple concurrent send requests on the same stream-oriented socket.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasend

Similarly, instead of spawning threads in `broadcastToClients`, I suggest you just spawn one persistent sender thread per client socket in `acceptClient` (together with the `receiveFromSocket` thread within some `createClientHandler`).

To communicate with the sender threads you should use thread-safe blocking queues. Each sender thread would look like this:

```
while (alive) {
  msg = queue.next_message();
  send(client_socket, msg);
}
```

Then on message received you just do:

```
for (client : clients) {
  client.queue.put_message(msg);
}
```

---

So to summarize, to handle each client you need a structure like this:

```
struct Client {
  int client_socket;
  BlockingQueue queue;

  // optionally if you want to keep track of your threads
  // to be able to safely clean up
  std::thread recv_thread, send_thread;
};
```

Safe cleanup is a whole other story.

---

Finally, a remark on this comment in your code:

```
        // Wait for all threads to finish
        for(std::thread& t : threads)
        {
            t.detach();
        }
```

That's almost the opposite to what `std::thread::detach` does:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach
It allows you to destroy the thread object without having to wait for the thread to finish execution.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown, I am still new to these topics and I appreciate any and all knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

There is a misconception in the code in how a TCP server has to be implemented:

You seem to assume that you can have a single server socket file descriptor which can handle all communication. This is not the case. You must have a single dedicated socket file descriptor which is just used for listening and accepting incoming connections, and then you have one additional file descriptor for each existing connection.

In your code I see that you invoke `receiveFromSocket()` always with the listening socket. This is wrong. Also invoking `receiveFromSocket()` in a loop for all clients is wrong.

What you rather need to do is:
- Have one dedicated thread which call accept() in a loop. There is no performance benefit in calling accept() from multiple threads.
- One accept() returns a new connection you spawn a new thread which calls recv() in a loop. This will then block and wait for new data as you expect in your question.

You also need to drop the habit of calling individual functions from new threads. This is not multithreaded programming. A thread usually contains a loop. Everything else is usually a design flaw.

Also note that multithreaded programming is still rocket science in 2019, especially in C++. If you are not an absolute expert you will not be able to do it. Also note that absolute experts in multithreaded programming will try to avoid multithreaded programming whenever possible. A lot seemingly concurrent tasks which are I/O bound can better be handled by a single threaded event based system.

Comment: Yeah I've heard its very difficult! I find multi threading exciting though and want to get better at it. I'll keep in mind that single threaded is preferred! Also i'll look into event based systems so thanks for the tip.